# Python converting tweepy tweet and user IDs to scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, variables, twitter

I was trying to do some data mining with twitter and ran into this problem. Python keeps converting the tweet's large numerical id's to scientific notation when I try to write it to a CSV file. For example, if the ID was 9381435503399854 python will convert it to 9.381435503399854E+17. I tried using `format(int(tweet.id), ".0f")` but it is giving me the same result. `Format(int(tweet.id), "f")` seems like it works but appends ".000000" to the end of the id. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is some sample code:

```
writeExtended(count, tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf8'), tweet.display_text_range, tweet.created_at)

def writeExtended(id, idstr, full_text, display_text_range, created_at):
    #Write Extended tweet details to CSV file
    with open('Extended.csv', mode='a+') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        employee_writer.writerow([id,idstr, full_text, display_text_range, created_at])
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using? I suggest converting `tweet.id` to text and saving that.

Comment: @MartinEvans just added the code. I tried converting it to text, it does not seem to help.

Comment: What does `print(type(idstr), idstr)` display?  Also you should add `newline=""` as a parameter to your `open()`

Comment: @MartinEvans it prints out <class 'int'> 1039263104541093888

Comment: Don't get tweet.id but tweet.id_str instead (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html) and when you open the CSV, make sure to set the column as "standard" or "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your script is working perfectly and that the effect you are seeing (i.e. conversion to scientific format) is a result of the conversion of the CSV file into Excel (or other spreadsheet application). You should try opening the CSV file in a text editor such as Notepad.

As a slightly bizarre workaround, you can convert it to text and prefix a tab character to it. This should stop the conversion:

```
def writeExtended(id, idstr, full_text, display_text_range, created_at):
    #Write Extended tweet details to CSV file
    with open('Extended.csv', mode='a+', newline='') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file)
        employee_writer.writerow([id, '\t{}'.format(idstr), full_text, display_text_range, created_at])

writeExtended(count, tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf8'), tweet.display_text_range, tweet.created_at)
```

Comment: Turns out the csv file was fine. Excel was just converting the numbers to scientific notation for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel, Libre Office and Google Spreadsheets import numeric-only cells as the number, so if it is a long string of a number (e.g. tweetid) then they convert it to scientific notation.

A workaround solution is to append a non-numeric text ( underscore character `_` for example)  to the number when you output your csv file from Python.

Another solution that **works only with Libre Office Calc**, when you open a csv file it will pop-up a menu before loading it. So if **select the column** you want to be treated as text, and then from the menu just above **change the "Column type" to  "Text"**,  and **hit OK**, then it will load the column without converting it to scientific notation. See the image below for visual illustration.

[image]